# Showing that $G/G_m$ and $G/G_n$ are isomorphic groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of complex numbers of modulus $1$ and let $G_n$ (with $n$ a positive integer) be the subgroup consisting of the $n$-th roots of unity. For positive integers $m$ and $n$, I want to show that $G/G_m$ and $G/G_n$ are isomorphic groups.

I can't even prove that the natural map is well defined. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Show that $G/G_m$ is   isomorphic to $G$ by defining a homomorphism $G \to G$ with kernel $G_m$

Comment: I understand... Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For every $n$ the map $\Bbb{C}^{\times}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{C}^{\times}:\ z\ \longmapsto\ z^n$ is a *surjective* group homomorphism with kernel $G_n$, so by the first isomorphism theorem $G/G_n\cong G$.